# Why does the :race_condition_ttl option for Rails.cache.fetch still block the first request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

The :race_condition_ttl option for Rails.cache.fetch seems REALLY close to what I want: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch

But it seems like it still blocks the first request that encounters an expired value (it's only subsequent requests after that which get the old value and return quickly while the cache is being updated).

I guess I'm surprised it doesn't serve the first expired request the same way and was wondering if there was a common pattern for this or if it had to be custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up monkey patching something like this for now: https://gist.github.com/4062316

Not sure how safe it is yet, but seems to be working.  Would be awesome to see something like this in the standard Rails.cache though.

Answer (score 0):

I used another way to resolve this: **don't set expires_in, only force cache miss if it's requested from saying admin.**

I have the rails app in two environments: admin and production. Production never expires cache. Admin always force cache miss on pages.

Once you have built all the caches. It never expires. Except you can do that from admin. Since admin is guaranteed the first visit of those web pages, with :race_condition_ttl, this method works pretty well.